# Combination of index and match in Excel is checking only the first row repeatedly

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have an Excel sheet in which there is some data. I want to pick a particular value from the 3rd column based on the conditions in the following formula

=INDEX($B:$O,MATCH(1,($B:$B=$Q2)*($E:$E="CE")*($M:$M=R2),0),3)

It is resulting in #N/A. I checked step calculations and noticed that $M:$M=R2 is checking only the value that is present in cell M2 repeatedly whereas it should be checking all the cells in column M

I have described the step calculations above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter the formula as array entry with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. Also use `*` asterisk between each condition.

```
=INDEX($B:$O,MATCH(1,($B:$B=$Q2)*($E:$E="CE")*($M:$M=R2),0),3)
```

And if you have access to `FILTER()` function then could try

```
=FILTER($D:$D,($B:$B=$Q2)*($E:$E="CE")*($M:$M=R2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. I was struggling with this for the past so many hours. Can you pls explain what's going on here?

Comment: Which one are you using INDEX() or FILTER()?

Comment: I used index( )